# Flutter on Microsoft Windows

Tags: flutter, windows, installation

I have already installed visual studio 2022 with Windows 10 SDK,
but running flutter doctor, i have a  return message:
! Unable to locate a Windows 10 SDK. If building fails, install the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio.
So flutter can't detect it.

Can anyone suggest me what other actions to do?